# AWS Lambda - Communicate with Apple Push Notification services

Tags: aws-lambda, apple-push-notifications, gateway, vpc

I recently deployed my backend on AWS Lambda and remote notifications for my iPhone app are not working anymore. From what I understand, it is due to the fact that Lambda functions cannot talk to the outside world without using an Internet Gateway with AWS. I need help setting that up! I could not find any tutorials online. Do I need to set a gateway between Lambda and Apple Push Notification services directly or a gateway between Lambda and the internet in general? How do I do that?

Comment: Lambda can by default talk to the outside world unless you put the Lambda function within a VPC (Even then you can configure a NAT Gateway to allow outbound connections).

Comment: Do I configure a NAT Gateway to allow specific outbound connections to Apple Push Notification services? Or to allow general outbound connections anywhere?

Comment: And is it a NAT gateway or Internet gateway I need?

Comment: Do you place your Lambda inside a VPC?

Comment: What makes you think that this is the problem? What error are you receiving? If you merely wish for the Lambda function to communicate with the Internet (and no resources in a VPC), so not configure a VPC on the function. Are you communicating with Apple directly, or via Amazon SNS?

Comment: Both my Lambda function and my RDS are in a VPC (I followed a tutorial that explained they had to be in the same VPC). It might be worth mentioning that my lambda function has a security group (also from the tutorial). I am using the django-push-notifications package which reads my Apple Certificate file and communicates with Apple directly.

Comment: My code gets stuck on the line 'device.send_message(...)' which should send a remote notification to another user of my mobile app through Apple. I don't get any errors. The AWS Lambda function simply times out after 30 seconds. When my backend was deployed in another server, push notifications worked well. I assumed that my code gets stuck on that line because it can't communicate with Apple.

Comment: I was able to fix it! This helped me out https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7